# VBNET Overload because no accessible 'int' accepts number arguments

Tags: vb.net, button

I'm getting this visual basic 2010 error : Overload resolution failed because no accessible int accepts number arguments.
Error at line2 'int'

```
Private Sub cmdadd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdadd.Click
    Dim i As Integer = Int.Parse(txtqfire.Text)
    i += 1
    txtqfire.Text = i.ToString()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is vb.net isn't it?

It should be:

```
Integer.Parse(txtqfire.Text)
```

You can also use:

```
Int32.Parse(txtqfire.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method in VB.NET (unlike c#).

The VB.NET conversion is:

```
Integer.Parse(txtqfire.Text)
```