# Values being passed as strings and not integers

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to collect a series of values as a string and then insert them to an SQL server dB. I have this working fine with just 'VarChar', but when I try to load collumns that contain numbers is fails.

It keeps throwing the below error about converting from string to integer.

"Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32."

Please can somebody help me with the correct syntax.

Below is a copy of my code:

```vb
    Dim table As New DataTable()

    table.Columns.Add("CallType")
    table.Columns.Add("ChargeCode")
    table.Columns.Add("Destination")
    table.Columns.Add("TariffUsed")
    table.Columns.Add("Peak")
    table.Columns.Add("OffPeak")
    table.Columns.Add("Weekend")
    table.Columns.Add("Setup")
    table.Columns.Add("Minimum Charge")
    table.Columns.Add("Charge Cap")
    table.Columns.Add("Initial Units")
    table.Columns.Add("Initial Charge")
    table.Columns.Add("Initial Peak")
    table.Columns.Add("Initial Off Peak")
    table.Columns.Add("Initial Weekend")
    table.Columns.Add("Billing Unit")
    table.Columns.Add("Minimum Units")
    table.Columns.Add(" RateType")

    'open file dialog and store filename
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim strFileName As String

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\Barry\Documents\Indigo Billing dB\Daisy Call Rates"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv"
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

    End If
    strFileName = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName
    If strFileName <> "" Then

        'TextField Parser is used to read the files 
        Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(openFileDialog1.FileName)

        MessageBox.Show("New Rate Card Loaded...", "Indigo Billing", _
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        parser.Delimiters = New String() {","} ' fields are separated by comma
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True ' each of the values is enclosed with double quotes
        parser.TrimWhiteSpace = True

        '--First line is skipped , its the header
        parser.ReadLine()

        '-- Add all the rows to datatable
        Do Until parser.EndOfData = True
            table.Rows.Add(parser.ReadFields())
        Loop

        '--Create SQL query
        Dim strSql As String = "INSERT INTO DaisyRatesImport (CallType,ChargeCode,Destination,TariffUsed,Peak,OffPeak,Weekend,Setup,Minimum Charge,Charge Cap,Initial Units,Initial Charge,Initial Peak,Initial Off Peak,Initial Weekend,Billing Unit,Minimum Units, RateType) VALUES (@CallType,@ChargeCode,@Destination,@TariffUsed,@Peak,@OffPeak,@Weekend,@Setup,@Minimum Charge,@Charge Cap,@Initial Units,@Initial Charge,@Initial Peak,@Initial Off Peak,@Initial Weekend,@Billing Unit,@Minimum Units, @RateType)"
        Dim SqlconnectionString As String = "server=barry-laptop\SQLEXPRESS; database=Test; integrated security=yes"
        Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(SqlconnectionString)

            Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSql, connection) ' create command objects and add parameters
            With cmd.Parameters

                .Add("@CallType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "CallType")
                .Add("@ChargeCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "ChargeCode")
                .Add("@Destination", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "Destination")
                .Add("@TariffUsed", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "TariffUsed")
                .Add("@Peak", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Peak")
                .Add("@OffPeak", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "OffPeak")
                .Add("@Weekend", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Weekend")
                .Add("@Setup", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Setup")
                .Add("@Minimum Charge", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Minimum Charge")
                .Add("@Charge Cap", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Charge Cap")
                .Add("@Initial Units", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Initial Units")
                .Add("@Initial Charge", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Initial Charge")
                .Add("@Initial Peak", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Initial Peak")
                .Add("@Initial Off Peak", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Initial Off Peak")
                .Add("@Initial Weekend", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Initial Weekend")
                .Add("@Billing Unit", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Billing Unit")
                .Add("@Minimum Units", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Minimum Units")
                .Add("@ RateType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, " RateType")

            End With

            Dim adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
            adapter.InsertCommand = cmd

            '--Update the original SQL table from the datatable
            Dim iRowsInserted As Int32 = _
                adapter.Update(table)

        End Using
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No File Selected", "Indigo Billing", _
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End If

    'displayes file name in Textbox1
    TextBox1.Text = strFileName

End Sub
```

I have had a search on here and believe I might need to convert them, but I am not sure what I am converting them to or from.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL Command has parameter values with two words: `@Minimum Charge,@Charge Cap,@Initial Units` You can't do that. Do this instead: `@MinimumCharge,@ChargeCap,@InitialUnits`

Comment: Thank you, I will make sure I remove the spaces :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to mark your columns with data type like

```
table.Columns.Add("CallType", GetType(Integer))
table.Columns.Add("ChargeCode", GetType(Integer))
table.Columns.Add("Destination", GetType(string))
table.Columns.Add("TariffUsed", GetType(string))
```

I have just marked them randomly. This will work for you as Column will be of specific data type and solve your issue of conversion.

Comment: typeof is C#.  VB.Net is GetType

Comment: use `table.Columns.Add("CallType",GetType(Integer))` the answer is using C# code.  `int` isnt in VB (use Integer or Int32) and `typeof` works differently in VB

Comment: Thanks @onskee.You need to parse your values before you add them in table please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153907/vbnet-overload-because-no-accessible-int-accepts-number-arguments

Comment: I added the GetType syntax, it now tells me "Type 'int' is not defined." Where/How does that need to be defined? Thanks

Comment: 'int' is nothing in VB.NET please use Integer as corrected in answer now.

Comment: I have added (integer) as per the suggestion above. The error msg now reads "Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <0.0122> in Peak Column.  Expected type is Int32.". I have also tried (int32), but to no avail.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to save Double value in Int32/Integer try to make that particular column as Double.

Comment: Thanks @Dnyanesh Double did the trick - Unfortunately I now get "Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'Charge'." Any ideas?

Comment: @user3580480  the error suggests that you did you not remove all the spaces.  the posted code has 2 instances of `charge` as "Minimum Charge" and "initial Charge"